# Using jquery.cookie plugin to set variable value from html and read that value from an external script

Tags: jquery, html, perl, cookies

I am not a jquery person and I need to use jquery.cookie plugin to save a variable value from html/perl to a cookie like (its just a psuedo code) :

```
my $user  = $q->param('user'); 
   $user = "JAKE"; 
.....
`<script>`
document.cookie = 
     'ppkcookie=logincookie; user=$user path=/' 
`</script>`
```

Then read the value of $user from an external script that I have which creates links to the webpage and is used throughout the application, here is the line where I want to assign value of $user where it says '+ user+' :

```
document.writeln('<div class="dc-rnav"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Go Back">Go Back</a> | <a href="login.pl" title="This will log you out">Log out</a> | <a href="" title="" >'+ user+ '</a></div>');
```

Many many thnaks !!

Tonya

EDITS:

OK here's what I have done in the perl/html to store $user value to a cookie :

```
my $user  = $q->param('user'); 
   $user = "JAKE"; 
   .....

`$.cookie("user", $user, { path:"/", expires:365 });`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>`
```

The js script I want to read and assign $user value to is a menu script and when I add the following line to it, the menu disappears off the webpage :

```
var user= $.cookie('user')|| "qualcuno";
```

`document.writeln('<div class="dc-rnav"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Go Back">Go Back</a> | <a href="login.pl" title="This will log you out">Log out</a> | <a href="" title="" >\'+ user+ \'</a></div>');`

Any idea as to why its behaving like this, is there anything we can do to make it work within the same js script.

Thanks much for your help!!

EDIT 2:

If I wrap it in a function within the JS Script it does not dislaunches itself from the web page, here is the function :

```
function readCookie(name) { 
     var user =$.cookie('user')|| "qualcuno"; 
     }
```

Now question is how do I call it and fit to the line where I want to get  '+ user +'

Thanks much !!

Comment: -1 Too much jQuery! You don't need jQuery to set a cookie, you can do it with Perl using CGI/Dancer/Mojolicious/Catalyst/whatever.

Comment: I know I can use perl to do that but I need to read the cookie contents through a jquery script which is used globally in my application, your help would be much appreicated !!

Comment: You happen to know some book which cover jquery cookies, please let me know - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Create the cookie in your first page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.cookie('user', $user, { expires: 1, path: '/' }); 
</script>
```

Step 2. Add the following to your Java script :

```
var user= $.cookie('user') ;
document.writeln('<div class="dc-rnav"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" title="Go Back">Go Back</a> | <a href="login.pl" title="This will log you out">Log out</a> | <a href="" title="" >'+ user +'</a></div>');
```